# Suddenly my C# code stopped bringing SPO user profiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, sharepoint-search, keywordquery

My code was working properly in development and production environments. All of a sudden stopped working after Mon 2022-06-27 12:00 AM.

It works properly in Production environment but in Development environment it is not bringing any users from SPO.

What could be the possible reason why it is not bringing any user profile using C#? When I use PowerShell with the same account, I am able to retrieve users. So it is not permission related.

Here is the C# code:

````
keywordQuery.HiddenConstraints = "scope:\"People\"";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "*";
keywordQuery.RankingModelId ="D9BFB1A1-9036-4627-83B2-BBD9983AC8A1";
keywordQuery.SourceId = new Guid("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31");
keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
keywordQuery.RowLimit = 500;
keywordQuery.StartRow = startRow;

SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(ctx);
ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
ctx.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry(20, 20);```
````

Comment: whenever you have code that works fine in one context, but not in another, the problem is probably not the code, but the context. Something changed on 6/26. Find out what that is, and you figure it out.

Comment: @DerekGusoff, Thank you for your suggestion. It is difficult to find out what has changed. There are too many people working on this development tenant. I need some pointers to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried removing RankingModelId and HiddenConstraints. It was not bringing user profiles that I was looking for.

Finally, I installed VS2022. After that it started working but it is still not working with HiddenConstraints.

After that, I updated my VS2019 and I experienced the same behavior in VS2019.

I can live with this but it would have been nice to know what was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false` OR `keywordQuery.RankingModelId ="D9BFB1A1-9036-4627-83B2-BBD9983AC8A1";`  and see if that works in your development.